# Redis "HEXIST" query format

Tags: redis, hashmap

`HEXISTS` query should be as follow: `HEXISTS` key field
and according to Redis documentation:

> In Redis, the `HEXISTS` command allows us to check whether a field
> exists in a given hash.

what exactly does "field" mean and does the key can include multiple values as fields?
and if I want to use the database as a set with the time running advantage of hashmap, should I insert an empty "field"?

Answer (score 0):

Hashes in redis is like javascript objects. for example

```
  student:{id:1, name:"name", age:23}
```

- Note that hashes does not allow deeply nested objects

If you run

```
  HEXISTS student name
```

It will check if "name" property or `field` exists in "student" obj. If it exists it will return 1 if not it will return 0.

If I set an hash like this

```
HSET student id 1 name "name" name 2 age 23
```

this will return 3 indicating that 3 fields of "student" hash updated. If I run this command to get the entire student hash

```
HGETALL student
```

It will return this object. only one "name". second "name" override the first one

```
{
  "name": "2",
  "id": "1",
  "age": "23"
}
```

- Note that redis does not check for truthness. if `name=false` it will count "false" as a value. because it only checks for the existence of the key